# Matrix devision - Bias Variance Tradeoff

Tags: complex-analysis, statistics, machine-learning, regularization

I am currently trying to prove that the ordinary least squares estimate doesn't have a bias with a given dataset [image]

with the bias given as

[image]

Why does this identity hold in the following calculation $$(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)\theta = \theta ?$$

The matrix $X$ is assumed to be fixed in this case.

[image]

Comment: If $(X^TX)$ is invertible then $(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)=I$

Comment: AH, I didn't see that. Does that come from the fact, that the model is overparameterized? There's only one more hint saying that $n >> d$, which doesn't add anything because it's not defined what n and d are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ is the number of samples and $d$ is the number of features.

$n >> d$ does not ensure the invertibility of $X^TX$.

If $X$ has $d$ linearly independent columns, then $X^TX$ is invertible. If $X$ follows certain distribution, say $X$ are samples drawn from contious uniform distribution or normal distribution, then the probability that it is invertible is $1$.

Hence we can write the notation $(X^TX)^{-1}$, being the inverse of $X^TX$, multiplying them both would give us the identity matrix.

Comment: That's interesting and answers my question fully, thanks! For which distributions does this hold apart from a continuous uniform distribution?

Comment: The important thing is that the samples can draw points that are not restricted to a plane. I.e. the sample points have to span the whole space.